# Amazon S3 Sync error: argument --include: expected 1 argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload some files to an Amazon S3 bucket. I first want to exclude all files, then include various individual files/folders. But I am getting:

```
aws: error: argument --include: expected 1 argument
```

I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters for reference.

Here is the command I'm trying to run:

```
aws s3 sync /deploy/ s3://my-bucket/ --delete --acl public-read --recursive \
        --exclude "*" \
        --include "*.html" \
        --include "assets/"
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the quotes are likely being replaced by the shell.

Use single quotes instead of double quotes to avoid this happening.